# Meaning of single colon in Haskell :t

Tags: haskell

As far as I've been able to gather, the single colon in Haskell is used in list comprehension. Why then does it show up in the :t command? Also in the :quit command? There isn't any list comprehension being done, is there?

Comment: The prefix colon is for GHCi commands. They only work inside the interactive interpreter and are not, as such, a part of the Haskell language. For example, you cannot use them inside a .hs file.

Comment: @SimonShine So the colon was just picked as convention? Can functions/variables use : in their names?

Comment: @Bob The colon character must begin every infix constructor. IE: `data Foo a = a :~ Bar`. The infix fuction `(:)` is the list constructor.

Comment: and you cannot define any other operator starting with `:` - but it might contain them - so `let (:$) ...` will not work but  `let ($:) ...` is ok

Comment: @AJFarmar Certainly, but you're not implying that this is an infix constructor, are you?

Comment: no - `:t`, `:i`, `:m` ... are just commands you pass on to GHCi while you are using it - it's not part of your program/script

Comment: @Bob No, an infix constructor must consist entirely of non-alphanumeric characters. Commands such as `:type`, `:load` etc are GHCi commands which *only have meaning at all in GHCi*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:t` (short for `:type`) syntax is special to GHCi, and is *not* part of the Haskell language syntax. This is similar to how the SQLite interpreter accepts `.tables` as a command, even though this isn't valid a SQL statement. If you type `:?`, you can see a complete list of all the commands GHCi understands.

As for using the colon in actual Haskell code:

- A colon by itself is a list constructor. This is a reserved name, and can never be redefined.
- You should know that function names always start lowercase, while constructor names always start uppercase. Well, in a similar way, an infix constructor *must* start with a colon, whereas a normal infix operator *must not* start with a colon (but may contain colons elsewhere).

So, for example, "`?:?`" is a legal operator name, and `:??` is a legal constructor operator name.

```
x ?:? y = ...whatever...

data Foobar = Int :?? Bool
```

Comment: I'd add that in _type operators_, the colon can be used just like any other infix symbol, e.g. you can define both `type a :& b = a` and `type a &: b = b`.

Comment: In GHC, I believe an infix *type* constructor does not need to start with a colon.